# Odd usage to set value to zero in for-loop

Tags: c++

I came across this for-loop, something i haven't encountered before, didn't know it was possible. Personaly i would set `sum = 0` between the 2 `for` loops and not where it is now.

How is it possible `sum` doesn't get set to 0 everytime `student_index` is increased, is it because the compiler only looks once at the first condition of the second for-loop when it's initialized and after that only increases `student_index` until the second condition is met?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int test_index, student_index, scores[3][5] = {
        {92, 73, 57, 98, 89},
        {88, 76, 23, 95, 72},
        {94, 82, 63, 99, 94}
    };
    float sum;

    for (test_index = 0; test_index < 3; test_index++) {
        sum = 0; // This is where i would set `sum = 0`
        for (student_index = 0, sum = 0; student_index < 5; student_index++) {
            sum = sum + scores[test_index][student_index];
        }
        cout << "Average score for test nr. " << test_index + 1 << ": "
                << sum / 5 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code, `som` vs. `sum`. Please copy-and-paste *exact* code.

Comment: It's bad code -- likely to confuse the reader, but as others have pointed out, it's valid -- unlikely to confuse the compiler.

Comment: And make clear what construct you're asking about. As it currently stands, `sum` is set to zero in the spot that you say you'd expect it to be set. So your confusion is confusing.

Comment: @KeithThompson fixed. :) thought i had them all. Usually i change everything to english for easy reading.

Comment: For future reference, you might consider first making sure your (simplified and/or translated) source compiles before copy-and-pasting it into your question. It can be difficult to tell whether a typo is related to the problem you're asking about.

Comment: @KeithThompson i'll triple check next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it because the compiler only looks once at the first condition of the second for-loop when it's initialized and after that only increases student_index until the second condition is met?

Yes.

---

The `for` syntax is:

```
for (init; condition; increment)
```

in this case, the `init` statement makes use of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

The result ends up being something like:

```
init;
while (condition) {
    ...
    increment;
}
```

And in this case init has multiple instructions because of the comma operator. So multiple things happen before the loop body and don't repeat inside the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the great answer(s). Somehow this position of `sum` sort of makes cleaner code, maybe i'll start using it like this in the future.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of how a for loop works

`for (<initial expression(s)>; <condition>; <iteration(s)>)`

Each of those parts can be a full expression (which includes a comma-separated list of expressions).

Comment: Almost true, except they're *expressions,* not *statements.* You can't put an `if` into the `for` header, for example.

Comment: @Angew well if we look at the grammer *for-init-statement* can include an *expression statement* which can surely include the comma operator. It can also include a *simple-declaration* which is not an expression. So the initial version was actually more correct it just needed the proper details, this version is actually misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent. The first (initialiser) clause of a `for` statement is only executed before the first iteration; so both `student_index` and `sum` are set to zero then. Between iterations, it executes the third (iteration) clause, then checks the second (condition) clause; neither of these do anything with `sum`.

If the initialser were executed each time, then the canonical `for` statement

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) whatever;
```

would loop forever, resetting `i` to zero each time, and the construct would be completely useless.

Comment: Taken that it is the initializer, it would be the correct spot to set everyting to 0 what you want to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.5.3` *The for statement* we can see this how `for` is described as follows:

> for ( for-init-statement condition<sub>opt</sub>; expression<sub>opt</sub>) statement
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>    for-init-statement
>    while ( condition ) {
>     statement
>     expression ;
>    }
>  }
> ```

We can see from section `6.5` that the *for-init-statement* is allowed to include an *expression statement*:

```
for-init-statement:
   expression-statement
   simple-declaration
```

which in this case uses the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), to initialize both `student_index` and `sum`:

```
student_index = 0, sum = 0 
                 ^
```